# How to apply multiple coupons in onepage checkout for one order? [

Tags: php, magento, checkout

I am working on Magento 1.9 CE and I want to know how multiple coupons are applicable for one order in onepage checkout. When user apply two coupons in checkout process new one coupon remove old one coupon, this is my problem. I want both coupons will work for one order. Please anybody help me about this problem. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento Multiple coupon codes for one order without extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138237/magento-multiple-coupon-codes-for-one-order-without-extension)